# Cocoapods declaring multiple dependecies in the spec file

Tags: cocoapods

Till now I always had only one dependency to declare in a .podspec file.

My question is:

What is the correct way to include more than one?

When I include only one, I do it like this:

```
s.dependency = 'ReactiveCocoa'
```

How do I include more than one?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can have multiple calls to `dependency` in your podspec file, for example in [RestKit.podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/ab1a764433f4ea108ddf3d2f732a972a313a375e/RestKit/0.20.3/RestKit.podspec):

```
s.subspec 'Core' do |cs|
    cs.source_files =  'Code/*.h', 'Vendor/LibComponentLogging/Core', 'Vendor/LibComponentLogging/NSLog'
    cs.header_dir   =  'RestKit'

    cs.dependency 'RestKit/ObjectMapping'
    cs.dependency 'RestKit/Network'
    cs.dependency 'RestKit/CoreData'
end
```